# How to get a value from a static page and post it into a model

Tags: python, django

I have showed the values {{ p.emri }} and {{ p.cmimi }} which are in the "Produkte" model onto my Browse.html. So far so good , but now I'm trying to write a function in views.py to get this values and post them into another model named "AddToCart" when i press the submit button.

I'm trying to write the views.py function where i'm thinking of getting the values first with a "GET" method and store them in variables then using a "POST" method to save those variables into the model "AddToCart"

This is the 'Browse.html' file where the values are shown from model "Produkt"

```
{% for p in produktet %}
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 on-over" style="...">
    <img class..." src="{{ p.foto }}">
    <label class="label-ge">{{ p.emri }}</label>
    <p><label style="...">{{ p.cmimi }} LEK</label></p>
    <h4>Pershkrimi</h4>
    <p>{{ p.pershkrimi }}</p>
    <button class="btn..." style="...">Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This are the "Produkt" and "AddToCart" models

```
class Produkte(models.Model):
    emri = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pershkrimi = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    cmimi = models.IntegerField()
    foto = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    kategori = models.ForeignKey(Kategorite, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)

def __str__(self):
    return self.emri

class AddToCart(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    id_product = models.ForeignKey(Produkte, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    orderd = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@property
def cmimi_total(self):
return self.quantity * self.id_product.cmimi
```

and this is the view function i'm trying to create

```
def buy_now(request):
    if request.method =='GET':
    price = browse(request.GET['p.cmimi'])
    emri = browse(request.GET['p.emri'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
```

i want to get the same values as p.emri and p.cmimi and store them into the AddToCart model, after that i have to get the stored values and show them into another static file but i can take care of that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your variables from a GET request, you need a POST request. You could use your add to card element on your page as a form submission button. The form you submit can contain the variable values you need as hidden input. For example:

```
<form method="post" action="your/add/to/cart/url/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="p.emri" value="{{ p.emri }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="p.cmimi" value="{{ p.cmimi }}">
```

Etc.

Then, in your views, you can access these values from the POST request and update your model instances:

```
def buy_now(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        price = browse(request.POST['p.cmimi'])
        emri = browse(request.POST['p.emri'])
```

Whenever you need to update anything, you should always POST your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I've just started working with python/django 2 weeks ago and i'm not used to them yet.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a steep learning curve with Django, but it's worth it. Let me know if there's anything unclear in my answer and I'll try to clarify this further. If my answer was useful to you please consider voting it up or marking it as the answer to your question, thanks!

Comment: what i'm trying to do right now is to store existing object atributte like name or quantity into another model

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do since it doesn't relate to your original question. It sounds like you need to set up a [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) from one model to another and access the attribute this way. Please upvote and/or accept my answer if it helped you with your original issue.

Comment: Great, my pleasure. I'd appreciate it if you would upvote my answer, thanks!

Comment: i upvoted it but since my reputation is less than 15  it's not shown...

Comment: Ah, right. You can mark it as the answer instead by using the grey tick symbol, thanks!